# spring boot 1.5.3 __ Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'jee'

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-boot

i try to connect to mysql using spring-boot but get :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'jee'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]     
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]    
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

**TpSpringMvc2Application :**

```
package org.opendevup;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class TpSpringMvc2Application {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SpringApplication.run(TpSpringMvc2Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**application.properties :**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jee
spring.datasource.data-username = root
spring.datasource.data-password =
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.properties.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>net.opendevup</groupId>
 <artifactId>scolarite</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>tp-spring-mvc2</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
     <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
    8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


 </project>
```

Comment: Can you connect directly to the database in question?

Comment: yes i can connect

Comment: `spring.jpa.properties.dialect` should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`. Instead you can also use `spring.jpa.database-platform`. And your username (and password) properties remove the `data-` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your properties are wrong

```
spring.datasource.data-username = root
spring.datasource.data-password =
```

Should be

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
```

And the dialect `spring.jpa.properties.dialect` should be

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

or

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

For the default properties see the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: thank you its working now, but still have one problem with the port : The "Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: That is unrelated. You probably have another application running on port 8080

Comment: yes it was, but i shut it down, and i still have the same problem

Comment: Which problem. That simply cannot be the case, as the message clearly states the port 8080 was in use, so there must be something still there or it is a different error. (note this isn't related anymore to your original issue and is basically a new question!).